# How to update Name field contents into Title field using SPD

Tags: workflow

I want to update title field from Name column immediately after file attachment in document library. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the **Update List Item** activity in SPD.

1. On the **Update List Item** dialog click the **Add** button
2. Set **Set this field** to Title
3. Click the **fx** button to the right of the **To this value** field
4. On the **Define Workflow Lookup** dialog, select **Name** from the **Field from Source** dropdown.
5. Click OK 3 times.

Should do the trick.

Comment: Didn't quite work here. I could add everything you said, but there is an extra section at the bottom of the Update List Item dialog box called Find the List Item, with a description that is typically not clear to me. Apparently this is required because if you leave them blank and click OK, the dialog box just stays there. I have tried several values for that section but always get an error when I try to run the workflow.