# Updating Name field contents into Title field w/o SPD

Tags: 2010, workflow

Essentially, I am looking to do the same thing covered in [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10286/how-to-update-name-field-contents-into-title-field-using-spd), without using SPD or VS. Is this possible?

Comment: Your link points to a Cisco MeetingPlace meeting, might want to change that!

Comment: Ooppss.. Changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In order to respond to the event of a new item (or a change to an item) you would need either a SPD workflow, or an event receiver written in Visual Studio. There is no other way to achieve this automatically when a document is uploaded.